# Asp.net c# File is used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, unmanagedresources

i am using Programming language C# asp.net 4.0. I have a situation where i upload an excel. Save it on hard drive using code then using SqlBulkCopy i dump all the content of this excel in to database. the code is working fine.

Problem arises if there is some problem any where in the program like i have less/Extra column in my excel file as specified in db. the exception is fired. i have handled the exception.

now if i again use the same file for upload it shows **file is used by another process and code breaks.**

Moreover even if file is dumped successfully. i cant upload same file due to same reason.

how can **i release or clean up the code or free this file for other processing after my exception occurs or my code runs successfully**

Comment: post some code where you are opening the file..

Comment: You're probably not closing a stream used to read/transport your data.

Comment: why not read the contents of the file from memory instead?

Answer (score 2):

You should close the file which you have opened for reading/writing. I guess you are doing that in simple scenario but when exception occurs you have not closed the file.make sure that you close the file in exception as well.

Comment: Thank you, i forgot to close the connection . Can you tell me how to close file in exception. i was using sqlbulkcopy